# Publishing Markdown posts from bitbucket to WordPress

Tags: deployment, markdown

I have a lot of markdown documents stored in a BitBucket repository.  The md documents change often so I use it to track changes.

I was now playing with the idea to 'publish' these MarkDown documents to a WordPress site.

Is it possible to setup a continuous deployment of MarkDown documents to a WorPress site.  And if so, any pointers on how to get this started?

Thx,

Comment: You can use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) to create new posts upon Github events firing, but the trigger list is quite limited (new issue, closed issue, new pull request, new repo).

Comment: Setup Cron to monitor changes - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible although it would take quite a bit of initial setup.

I recommend learning about [Bitbucket's webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html). This is how you would have Bitbucket essentially talk to your WordPress install. You would create a plugin or a theme template that has a physical url to it that you point the webhook to.

When a commit is made, bitbucket will send a payload to that url and a php script will update the existing post in the database based on the changes made. If it is a new markdown file, a new post is created, if the post already exists, it will update. This would of course be the hardest part of all of it.

See wp_update_post & [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) functions in the WordPress codex: